# NodeJS on existing php local site

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I have a site build on PHP / Apache, and i would like to insert a NodeJs application inside a div area, i have already it shown in an iframe like so :

```
<iframe src="http://example.com:8080"></iframe>
```

I tried ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse with the code below but it only redirect to my nodeJs app without my PHP site in the apache configuration file */etc/apache2/sites-available/exemple.conf*.

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

How can i achieve this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally no need of specific server configuration, an ajax call to the server url + port from the client do the job.

=> server.js file <=

```
// Use of socket.IO
var io = require('socket.io')(8080);
// Establishes server connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){
//send data to client ( real time date exemple )
  setInterval(function(){
    io.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
  }, 100);
});
```

=> script anywhere on the site web with css #date ID <=

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // Get base path
  var base_url = window.location.origin;
  // Establishes client connection to server
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : base_url + ':8080/socket.io/socket.io.js', // Socket.IO init on port (8080)
    dataType : 'script', // Turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests with 'script' type
    success : function(){
      // Connection to the server
      var socket = io(base_url + ':8080');
      // Get message defined server side
      socket.on('date', function(data){
        // Print msg into html
        jQuery('#date').text(data.date);
      });
    }
  });
});
```